# Can't get user description in Redux + Firebase

Tags: reactjs, redux

Although I have successfully fetched `users` and `profiles` but I don't know why this error below occurs:

> Cannot read property 'content' of undefined

```
{content: "Hello world", status: 2}
```

Initially, I use Firestore and this time fetch 2 docs from different collections, `users` and `profiles`.

redux code:

```js
export function fetchUser(id) {
  return dispatch => {
    usersRef
      .doc(id)
      .get()
      .then(doc => {
        profilesRef
          .where("uid", "==", id)
          .where("status", "==", doc.data().current_status)
          .get()
          .then(function(querySnapshot) {
            querySnapshot.forEach(function(snapshot) {
              const profileItems = { ...doc.data(), profiles: snapshot.data() };
              dispatch({
                type: FETCH_USER,
                payload: profileItems
              });
            });
          });
      });
  };
}
```

In container:

```
import { FETCH_USER } from "../actions";

const initialState = {};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    console.log("action", action.payload)
    // successfully fetched, user info and profiles: profiles info
    case FETCH_USER:
      return action.payload;

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

In view:

```js
function mapStateToProps({ users }) {
  console.log("content", user.profiles.content)
  // Cannot read property 'content' of undefined

  return { user: users, profiles: user.profiles };
}
```

reducer file:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers } from "redux";
import UsersReducer from "./reducer_users.js";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  users: UsersReducer,
});

const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(reduxThunk));
export default store;
```

Comment: Can you also share your root reducer file? The one that you use the `combineReducer()` in it.

Comment: you can learn more about how to use redux with react from my project https://github.com/karenaprakash/final-project.git

Comment: @evolon I have added root reducer file.

Comment: @k10a I'm not sure that the code above is the actual code or just a sample code, but anyway it seems that you're updating the state correctly... the issue arises when you want to subscribe to the state and re-render your component when it gets updated. **Specifically, in your connect method** where you reference `profiles: user.profiles` where there's no `user` in that scope.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are making mistack you are accessing user instead of users

```
function mapStateToProps({ users , content }) {

  console.log("content", user.profiles.content) // change user to users 
 console.log("content",content) // you can directly access content here

  return { user: users, profiles: user.profiles };
}
```

you can initialize default state here

add one more type FETCH_USER_COMPLETE

```
import { FETCH_USER } from "../actions";

const initialState = {
  content : '',
  users : ''
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    console.log("action", action.payload)
    // successfully fetched, user info and profiles: profiles info
    case FETCH_USER:
      return { ...state , action.payload };

 case FETCH_USER_COMPLETE :
      return { ...state , users : action.payload.users , content : action.payload.users.profiles.content };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But it doesn't work. Actually content has been successfully fetched but I can't understand how it shows in the view.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might not be best practice but I have solved like this:

from:

```
querySnapshot.forEach(function(snapshot) {
  const profileItems = { ...doc.data(), profiles: snapshot.data() };
  dispatch({
    type: FETCH_USER,
    payload: profileItems
  });
});
```

to:

```
querySnapshot.forEach(function(snapshot) {
  const userItems = { ...doc.data(), ...snapshot.data() };
  dispatch({
    type: FETCH_USER,
    payload: userItems
  });
});
```

I can get content like `{user.content}`.